# Difference between 1* + 0* and (1 + 0)*

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I know that `(1 + 0)*` is the set of all bit strings; but isn't  `1* + 0*` the same thing?

Comment: The second one is "all ones or all zeroes", which doesn't include e.g. 0101010

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The set $1^*+0^*$ is composed of two parts: $1^*$ and $0^*$. The first part, $1^*$, is all strings composed entirely of $1$s. The second part, $0^*$, is all strings composed entirely of $0$s. In contrast, $(1+0)^*$ is all strings composed of $0$s and $1$s. Can you now think of a string in $(1+0)^*$ but not in $1^*+0^*$?

Answer (score 0):

```
  (1*+0*)= 11.. or 00... but cannot produce 101010101
  (1+0)*= anything with 1 and 0
```

yeah: (1*+0*)* would be a different story.